# Why is my MS Access report changing the actual cents to .00 instead of real numbers?

Tags: decimal, report, ms-access-2010, currency

My table and subsequent queries all show actual numbers but for some reason the report is taking the cent value and changing it to .00 instead of the actual number coming from the query.[This is the table and query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8snen.png)[This is the report results for same numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFJvN.png)

Initially I had table set to currency on those fields and it was giving same results in report so I tried changing table number to general number but that didn't change the outcome. Report still changes the decimal places.

Comment: The Query results are 9.25, 0.555, 4.514, 4.2661 but report with standard text field displays 9, 0, 4, 4. With currency field it displays $9.00, $0.00, $4.00, and $4.00

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a second field, tried using original field as a Double but that blew my results into some astronomical figures so I switched original table field to single number and created a second field converting that to currency which the report then accepted as correct numbers...

I don't know why it works but it does...If someone could please explain it I'd very much appreciate it, because having multiple fields for the same data just seems redundant...

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that when you created the second field you also changed the output field in the report. If your report is dropping the decimals then you should check the Format and Decimal Places properties of the text box:

[image]